# Using Files API to read and write to .txt file, not the same as using BufferredWriter?

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader, outputstream

I am doing the [Text Editor](https://hyperskill.org/projects/38) project on Hyperskill and all is well except stage two test #18. I paid my gems to see the solution to this and I can't understand what the differnece is between my code and the successful code. I'm hoping someone can explain why it works and mine doesn't?

The error I get is;
"Text should be the same after saving and loading same file"

As far as I can see it is the same. I select all text with CTRL-A (In the `JTextArea`)and it selects the line breaks and spaces.

I cannot see what the difference is between my code and some correct solutions that pass the test. My code does what is required and input / output is in bytes, which should gather any white space characters or line breaks, right?

Can anyone tell me what the ultimate difference is between (save to file method) my unsuccessful code -

```java
try {
        Files.write(Path.of("./"
                            + textField.getText()),                     
                            textArea.getText().getBytes());
} catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is writing to the file in bytes, is it not? Compared to the successful code -

```java
String content = textArea.getText();
try (final BufferedWriter writer = 
             Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of("./"
                            + textField.getText()));) {
        writer.write(content);
        writer.flush();
} catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println("Cant save file" + ioException);
}
```

For reading a file, my unsuccessful code is -

```java
try {
         String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("./"
                                            + textField.getText())));
         textArea.setText(content);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
         ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```

The successful code is -

```java
try {
         textArea.setText(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))));
} catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("Cant read file!!!");
         return null;
}
```

What is the difference? I am using Files in a slightly different way but I can only see that it is getting bytes to strings or vice versa.

Comment: The reading is the same, provided the path is the same. The main difference in the writing code is the implicit codec. `textArea.getText().getBytes()` is going to assume a codec to convert the String to bytes. `Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of("./"
                            + textField.getText()));` When you create a writer it will have a default code. The other difference is your path names. Are you reading and writing to the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your path names are correct, then it's possible the two different write methods are using different codecs.

[String#getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) uses the platform default charset.

[Files.newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) uses UTF8.

So if your platform default is not utf8 then you could be writing different bytes. Maybe try.

```
string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Useful information, thank you. Sadly I made the changes and the test still fails. The .txt files are loading into the `JTextArea` and saving fine either way, I'm wondering if it is some issue with the test. I tried the `BufferedWriter` approach, which previously passed the tests, and now that is failing too. Is there anything else that you can see? Many thanks.

Comment: @SimonA Are you sure the paths are correct? They look quite different.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should clarify that the "successful" code is from someone elses implmentation of the project, so they have a different file path to where they're saving/loading files. Unless there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Turns out there was a path issue when I copied the code, but today it seems like `Files.write` and `Files.readAllBytes` pass the test. Maybe the tests are updated, but thank you for the info on `StandardCharsets` constants.